# Transfer TFS Work Item Queries from locally installed TFS to visualstudio.com

Tags: azure-devops

Is there any way to move custom queries I've setup in my company's locally hosted TFS server to my instance of TFS on visualstudio.com?  I've Googled/Binged/Yahoo'd and even DuckDuckGo'ed around and asked other devs using the service but none of them had any saved queries they wanted to move, so no one had done any researching yet.  After a few fruitless searches I've turned to the experts here on SO.  Anyone find anything about this they can share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual suspects when it comes to TFS Migration (namely the [TFS Integration Platform](http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/)) does not support moving project or personal queries.  Depending on the quantity of queries, a manual recreation is obviously possible.  However, if there are a significant number, then another option is to use the [TFS SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb286958.aspx) (`Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client` and `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client`).  Within there, you can access the "My Queries" and project queries, including their folder hierarchy.

One example of this is available on [Mike Poulson's blog](http://www.mikepoulson.com/2013/08/migrating-tfs-2010-or-2012-personal.html) where he shows going from a TFS 2010 -> TFS 2012 server.  While this example is targeting on-prem, the same holds true for a move from TFS on-prem to Visual Studio Online.

Some of the queries may need "translation" in the migration process (naming differences, etc), using the SDK can also help in that process.  So at the end of the day, it's a tradeoff between a manual recreation vs effort to code/debug/test a solution with the SDK.